# Xperia L not booting to TWRP

Tags: adb, twrp, fastboot

I installed TWRP in my rooted Sony Xperia L using the TWRP Official App. The app said that the flashing was successful. Then, when I give adb reboot recovery command, it boots into the stock recovery. Even when I try to reboot into recovery from the TWRP Official App, it boots into the stock recovery.
There is no TWRP whatsoever. Even when I try to boot with the hardware keys and/or fastboot, it either shows a blank screen with the blue notification LED ON or boots into the stock recovery. Please tell me what to do...

Comment: The Xperia L is one of the weird ones that utilizes the Fota partition. The stock recovery has an in boot arrangement. you using the stock kernel or boot image? If yes then does your stock boot image include ramdisk extraction utility? You might need some extra steps to get TWRP installed. What detailed steps did you attempt when trying to install TWRP?

Comment: @BoLawson I tried installing TWRP with the TWRP app as well as with fastboot . Also, I'm pretty noob to this FOTAOKerne thing. And yes, I'm using the stock boot image. What is ramdisk extraction utility ...?l

Comment: It is way to extract the ramdisk from the FOTA Kernel partition using the ramdisk from that partition. This allows you to have TWRP boot from the FOTA Kernel partition instead of the recovery that is included in the boot image. Pretty much you need either a custom kernel with TWRP inside, custom boot image, or stock kernel and boot image that can utilize the Fota Kernel partition for TWRP. The Fota partition was ment for OTA's but since custom firmware and it a do not mix. TWRP along with Free Xperia developers decided to utilize no longer device useful partition to have TWRP reside in.

Comment: What android version? What version of TWRP are you trying to install? What fastboot command did you use specifically where did you try to flash TWRP with fastboot? You might have to flash a custom rom first in order to support the fota kernel way. It is rare but some stock kernels might support the Fota way. Options: flash a custom kernel which has TWRP inside, install cm/lineageos then use the app to install TWRP, use Other boot images including stock kernels can be repacked to include this extraction utility to allow you to use TWRP from the FOTAKernel partition possibly a tool

Comment: Android Version: Jelly Bean. I tried installing using fastboot flash recovery TWRP.img. Also, I was trying to install Lineage OS [7.1.1] from TWRP. I just wanna install Lineage OS. That's my ultimate aim. If I can actually do that without Installing TWRP,  I just want that to happen. So, is there any way to do that..? I don't know how to install Lineage OS without TWRP.

Comment: That fastboot command did not work because there is no recovery partition. Recovery is the boot this is why twrp takes advantage of the un-used fotakernel partition. The CWM that came might flash 7.1.x but most likely you will need an updated version of TWRP in order to flash that firmware (CWM has been out of development for a long time). You should be able to flash an older lineage/cm through the stock CWM that takes that can access the fotakernel partition. Flash through `install zip from SD Card` option. Then you can use/or flash an updated TWRP. After that you can flash the 7.1.x lineage.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you're talking to a noob. Please explain a bit more...

Comment: No problem, right now the readon you are having trouble accessing TWRP is because the kernel (the kernel is like a middle man {mediator or brain}for system resources for apps. etc.) Does not know how to do it. So you need change it. You should be able to flash/install through your current stock recovery CWM by putting an older copy of lineage/cm on the device. Giving the kernel the knowledge for accessing to fota partition. Then flash an updated TWRP through the app. From there you can update lineageOS to 7.1.x.